# Using a custom PHP.INI for a single site. Windows 2003, 64bit, IIS7.5, PHP 5.3.6

Tags: windows-server-2003, iis-7.5, php5

I have a single PHP script on a single site that requires me to set the upload size maximum fairly high. I would prefer not to do this globally.

According to the PHP docs, I can not set the values for some variable such as `post_max_size` , `max_file_uploads` or `upload_max_filesize` using `ini_set`. I've seen a number of solutions here running PHP on a UNIX box or on Windows running Apache, but none that are clear to me using IIS.

My understanding is that there is a way for me to have a custom php.ini file to override specific php.ini value.

Ideally, I would love to have a php.ini file in the folder with that one script that looks something like this:

```
[PHP]
post_max_size = 200M
max_file_uploads = 5
upload_max_filesize = 200M
```

How can I accomplish this without setting the values globally on my server?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It's certainly possible to use different PHP settings for a specific website or to even use a different version of PHP per website. An article titled [Using FastCGI to Host PHP Applications on IIS 7](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/246/using-fastcgi-to-host-php-applications-on-iis/#Per-site_PHP_configuration) by Ruslan Yakushev on IIS.net explains how to set it up. It also contains other useful tips on how to set it up securely.